# Bitmaps on Azure BLOB storage - http or https, cache expire timespan

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I have a bunch of icon bitmaps for my website that are on Azure BLOB storage. I figure I should set the `img=` on them using http instead of https. No encryption is faster and there’s nothing secret in them. They’re PNG files on web pages that allow anonymous access.

Is there any problem I’ll hit doing this? Does Azure or browsers have any issues with http? Or will it be slower for some reason?

Also is there any way I can tell the browser that everything coming from the Azure CDN can be cached for a week? Or does that happen automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Azure or browsers have any issues with http?

There is a setting in Azure Storage that only allows serving content over HTTPS (and is set by default). The content won't be served in this case. You will need to turn off this setting for serving content over HTTP.

Furthermore, I have seen some browsers refuse to serve content over HTTP. For those browsers, the images won't be displayed.

> Also is there any way I can tell the browser that everything coming
> from the Azure CDN can be cached for a week? Or does that happen
> automatically?

Each blob in Azure Storage has a `Cache-Control` property. When this property is set, the content will be cached by user agents (browser in this case) for the duration of value specified in that property.

For caching of blob content in CDN, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-manage-expiration-of-blob-content.

Comment: Thank you - clearly using http would be problematic.